# Which is the easiest way to migrate a C++ application for Android and iOS?

Tags: android, c++, ios, visual-studio, cross-platform

I have a C++ application that uses Qt 4.8 and OpenCV 2.4.2. It is developped using Visual Studio. I have to migrate this application for Android and iOS.
Which is the plan to follow? I should make the minimal change to the existing code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unfortunately, there’s no easy answer to this.  The fact that you’re using Qt is a great start, and using it as much as possible will go a long way towards making your code portable from Windows to other OSes.

I would look at upgrading first to Qt 5, as Qt introduced great support for both iOS and Android.

After that, the build chain is going to be your next obstacle.  It looks like the Qt Visual Studio Add-in has an option to export a .pri file from the VC++ project, which would be a very handy starting point. Generate the .pri file and compare it to the project file created by QtCreator for an Android and iOS app, and try to copy the mobile-specific parts into your generated .pri file.

Other potential pitfalls are:

- Visual C++ is a much more permissive compiler than gcc (Android) or Clang (iOS and Android)
- Your app's dependencies must all be cross-platform as well.  I’m sure OpenCV is, but it’s something to keep in mind
- On iOS, all libraries must be linked statically

Comment: Thanks a lot. Very informtative! I have a little question: I use in my application many to C++ libraries that don't use Qt or OpenCV ( some of them I have the source to compile and the other I only have the compiled dll in Visual Studio). How can I port them to Android and iOS? I make a study and found that Visual studio have the possibility to compile shared C++ libraries for them, but I have no idea about the feasibilty of such a method. These libraries are in fact the great obstacle in the migration procedure.

Comment: Once again, it's very dependent on which libraries you are using, and how compatible THEY are with other platforms.  Visual Studio -- the IDE -- has some capabilities for compiling for Android and iOS, but it'll still be using the platform-specific compiler (LLVM/clang) instead of the Visual C++ compiler, and will need to include and link to the platform-specific headers and libraries.  So the fact that Visual Studio is the front-end only helps you a small amount.